# How do I make two seperate stopwatches controlled by two different stop and start buttons in tkinter gui. My computer wont let me

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, root

I am trying to make a timesheet where every employee times in in the morning and times out at the end of the day. It is going well so far but, I the
Why is the the Jimena stopwatch button controls are controlling the gagan stopwatch? I want the start and stop of each name to work seperetley (2, individual stopwatches)? Can you assist me?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


# JIMENA


class JimenaStopwatch():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.running = None

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        print("CLICKED")
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        if self.running == True:
            start["state"] = tk.DISABLED
            self.counter += 1
            timer["text"] = self.counter
            timer.after(1000, self.run)

    def stop(self):
        start["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.running = False
        self.run()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("750x500")
root.resizable(height=False, width=False)
stopwatch = JimenaStopwatch()
timer = ttk.Label(root, text=stopwatch.counter)

start = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=stopwatch.start, state=tk.NORMAL)
stop = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=stopwatch.stop)
jimena = Label(root, text="JIMENA", height=2, width=10)
jimena.grid(column=0, row=3)
start.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10)
stop.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=10)
timer.grid(column=5, row=3, padx=10)




# GAGAN


class GaganStopwatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.running = None

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        print("CLICKED")
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        if self.running:
            start["state"] = tk.DISABLED
            self.counter += 1
            timer["text"] = self.counter
            timer.after(1000, self.run)

    def stop(self):
        start["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.running = False
        self.run()


gagan = Label(root, text="GAGAN", height=2, width=10)
gagan.grid(column=0, row=4)


stopwatch = GaganStopwatch()
timer = ttk.Label(root, text=stopwatch.counter)

start = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=stopwatch.start, state=tk.NORMAL)
stop = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=stopwatch.stop)
start.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=10)
stop.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=10)
timer.grid(column=5, row=4, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic issue is that you have used the same (global) variables for both the stop watches. Use different variable names for the class *GaganStopwatch*:

```
class GaganStopwatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.running = None

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        print("CLICKED")
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        if self.running:
            start_1["state"] = tk.DISABLED
            self.counter += 1
            timer_1["text"] = self.counter
            timer_1.after(1000, self.run)

    def stop(self):
        start_1["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.running = False
        self.run()


gagan = Label(root, text="GAGAN", height=2, width=10)
gagan.grid(column=0, row=4)


stopwatch_g = GaganStopwatch()
timer_1 = ttk.Label(root, text=stopwatch_g.counter)

start_1 = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=stopwatch_g.start, state=tk.NORMAL)
stop_1 = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=stopwatch_g.stop)
start_1.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=10)
stop_1.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=10)
timer_1.grid(column=5, row=4, padx=10)
```

Comment: For something that needs to scale like this writing a new variable and a new set of buttons for each person is going to be a mess. It is better to use a list or dictionary in this case to dynamically manage all that.

Comment: @Mike-SMT know. Hence, I started my answer with _basic issue_. With tkinter, I would personally go with complete _OOP_ and no _global variables_